# ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: Customer.name cannot be null

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Al intentar crear un *customer* en insomnia me arroja el siguiente error; ya repase el código varias veces y no encuentro mi error del por qué envía todo nulo:

```
    {
    "statusCode": 409,
    "message": "SequelizeValidationError",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Customer.name cannot be null",
            "type": "notNull Violation",
            "path": "name",
            "value": null,
            "origin": "CORE",
            "instance": {
                "sendOffer": true,
                "createdAt": "2023-07-03T00:48:01.470Z",
                "id": null
            },
            "validatorKey": "is_null",
            "validatorName": null,
            "validatorArgs": []
        },
        {
            "message": "Customer.lastName cannot be null",
            "type": "notNull Violation",
            "path": "lastName",
            "value": null,
            "origin": "CORE",
            "instance": {
                "sendOffer": true,
                "createdAt": "2023-07-03T00:48:01.470Z",
                "id": null
            },
            "validatorKey": "is_null",
            "validatorName": null,
            "validatorArgs": []
        },
        {
            "message": "Customer.phone cannot be null",
            "type": "notNull Violation",
            "path": "phone",
            "value": null,
            "origin": "CORE",
            "instance": {
                "sendOffer": true,
                "createdAt": "2023-07-03T00:48:01.470Z",
                "id": null
            },
            "validatorKey": "is_null",
            "validatorName": null,
            "validatorArgs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Error** que arroja en terminal:

```
    ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: Customer.name cannot be 
    null,
    notNull Violation: Customer.lastName cannot be null,
    notNull Violation: Customer.phone cannot be null
    at InstanceValidator._validate (/home/practicas/e-wallet- 
    solo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:50:13)
    at async InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (/home/practicas/e-wallet- 
    solo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:60:7)
    at async InstanceValidator.validate (/home/practicas/e-wallet- 
    solo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:54:12)
    at async Customer.save (/home/practicas/e-wallet- 
    solo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2426:7)
    at async Customer.create (/home/practicas/e-wallet- 
    solo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1362:12)
    at async CustomerService.create (/home/practicas/e-wallet- 
    solo/services/customers.service.js:21:25)
    at async /home/practicas/e-wallet-solo/routes/customers.router.js:42:28 {
    errors: [
      ValidationErrorItem {
        message: 'Customer.name cannot be null',
        type: 'notNull Violation',
        path: 'name',
        value: null,
        origin: 'CORE',
        instance: [Customer],
        validatorKey: 'is_null',
        validatorName: null,
        validatorArgs: []
      },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Customer.lastName cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'lastName',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [Customer],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Customer.phone cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'phone',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [Customer],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Código de `customer.service`:

```
    const boom = require('@hapi/boom')
    const { models } = require('../libs/sequelize')

    class CustomerService {
      constructor() {}

    async find() {
      const customer = await models.Customer.findAll()
    return customer
    }

    async findOne(id) {
     const customer = await models.Customer.findByPk(id)
     if(!customer) {
      throw boom.notFound('customer not found')
    }
    return customer
    }

    async create(data) {
     const newCustomer = await models.Customer.create(data)
     return newCustomer
    }

    async update(id, changes) {
     const model = await this.findOne(id)
     const customer = await model.update(changes)
     return customer
    }

    async delete(id) {
     const model = await this.findOne(id)
     await model.destroy()
     return { rta: true }
    }
    }

    module.exports = CustomerService
```

Código del `index` de la carpeta `routes`:

```
const express = require('express')

const customerRouter = require('./customers.router')

function routerApi(app) {
  const router = express.Router()
  app.use('/v1/', router)
  router.use('/customers', customerRouter)
}

module.exports = routerApi
```

Código de `customer.router`:

```
    const express = require('express')

    const CustomerService = require('../services/customers.service')

    const validatorHandler = require('../middlewares/validator.handlres')
    const { getCustomerSchema, createCustomerSchema, updateCustomerSchema } = 
    require('../schemas/customer.schema')

    const router = express.Router()
    const service = new CustomerService()

    router.get('/',
      async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const customers = await service.find()
        res.json(customers)
      } catch (error) {
        next(error)
      }
    }
    )

    router.get(
      '/:id',
      validatorHandler(getCustomerSchema, 'params'),
      async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          const { id } = req.params
          const customer = await service.findOne(id)
          res.json(customer)
        } catch (error) {
          next(error)
      }
      }
     )

    router.post(
      '/',
      validatorHandler(createCustomerSchema, 'body'),
      async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          const body = req.body
          res.status(201).json(await service.create(body))
        } catch (error) {
          next(error)
        }
       }
      )

     router.patch(
       '/:id',
       validatorHandler(getCustomerSchema, 'params'),
       validatorHandler(updateCustomerSchema, 'body'),
       async (req, res, next) => {
         try {
           const { id } = req.params
           const body = req.body
           const customer = await service.update(id, body)
           res.json(customer)
         } catch (error) {
           next(error)
          }
        }
       )

     router.delete(
       '/:id',
       validatorHandler(getCustomerSchema, 'params'),
       async (req, res) => {
         const { id } = req.params
         const customer = await service.delete(id)
         res.json(customer)
      }
     )

     module.exports = router
```

Código de `customer.schema`:

```
    const Joi = require('joi')

    const id = Joi.number().integer()
    const name = Joi.string()
    const lastName = Joi.string()
    const email = Joi.string().email()
    const phone = Joi.string()
    const totalSpent = Joi.number().integer()
    const wallet = Joi.number().integer()
    const sendOffer = Joi.boolean()

    const getCustomerSchema = Joi.object({
      id: id.required()
    })

    const createCustomerSchema = Joi.object({
      name: name,
      lastName: lastName,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      sendOffer: sendOffer
    })

    const updateCustomerSchema = Joi.object({
      name,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      totalSpent,
      wallet,
      sendOffer,
    })

    module.exports = { getCustomerSchema, createCustomerSchema, updateCustomerSchema }
```

Les añado el `customer.model`:

```
    const { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')

    const CUSTOMER_TABLE = 'customers'

    const CustomerSchema = {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'last_name',
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        aunique: true
      },
      phone: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      totalSpent: {
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'total_spent',
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      wallet: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      sendOffer: {
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'send_offer',
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'create_at',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
      }
    }

    class Customer extends Model {
      static associate() {
       //
      }

       static config(sequelize) {
         return {
          sequelize,
          tableName: CUSTOMER_TABLE,
          modelName: 'Customer',
          timestamps: false
        }
       }
      }

       module.exports = { CUSTOMER_TABLE, CustomerSchema, Customer }
```

Código del `index` de la carpeta `model`:

```
const { Customer, CustomerSchema } = require('./customer.models')

function setupModels(sequelize) {
  Customer.init(CustomerSchema, Customer.config(sequelize))
}

module.exports = setupModels
```

En el `customer.models` eliminé los **allowNull** y si se creo pero todo estaba en **null**.

Código de la carpeta `config` archivo `config`:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const config = {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev',
  isProd: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  dbUrl:  process.env.DATABASE_URL
}

module.exports = { config }
```

Código de `config` de la carpeta `models`:

```
const { config } = require('../config/config')

module.exports = {
  development: {
    url: config.dbUrl,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
  production: {
    url: config.dbUrl,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
}
```

Código de las **migraciones**:

```
'use strict'

const { CUSTOMER_TABLE } = require('../models/customer.models')

module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable(CUSTOMER_TABLE, {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'last_name',
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      phone: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING
      },
      totalSpent: {
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'total_spent',
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      wallet: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      sendOffer: {
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'send_offer',
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'created_at',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn("NOW")
      }
    })
  },

  async down (queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable(CUSTOMER_TABLE)
  }
}
```

Código de `sequelize`:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const { config } = require('../config/config')

const setupModels = require('../db/models')

const options = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: config.isProd ? false : true
}

if(config.isProd) {
  options.dialectOptions = {
    ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.dbUrl, options)

setupModels(sequelize)

module.exports = sequelize
```

Código de los `middlewares`:

`errorHandler`:

```
const { ValidationError } = require("sequelize")
const boom = require('@hapi/boom')

function logErrors (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err);
  next(err);
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack,
  });
}

function boomErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.isBoom) {
    const { output } = err;
    res.status(output.statusCode).json(output.payload);
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
}

function ormErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err instanceof ValidationError) {
    res.status(409).json({
      statusCode: 409,
      message: err.name,
      errors: err.errors
    })
  } else {
    next(err)
  }
}


module.exports = { logErrors, errorHandler, boomErrorHandler, ormErrorHandler }
```

`validator.handler`:

```
const boom = require('@hapi/boom')

function validatorHandler(schema, property) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const data = req[property]
    const { error } = schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false })
    if (error) {
      next(boom.badRequest(error))
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
}

module.exports = validatorHandler
```

Código del `index` del proyecto:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const routerApi = require('./routes')

const { logErrors, errorHandler, boomErrorHandler, ormErrorHandler } = require('./middlewares/error.handler')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.json())

const whiteList = [ 'http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:3000' ]

const options = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if(whiteList.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('No Permitido'))
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors(options))

routerApi(app)

app.use(logErrors);
app.use(ormErrorHandler);
app.use(boomErrorHandler);
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port)
```

Esta es la ruta que utilizo en insomnia para crear un *customer*.

http://localhost:3000/v1/customers

Así es como estoy intentando crear un customer desde insomnia

```
    {
        "name": "ed",
        "lastName": "cam",
        "email": "ed@cam.com",
        "phone": "667545454",
        "totalSpent": 100,
        "wallet": 10,
        "sendOffer": true
    }
```

Estas son todas las dependecias que tengo instaladas y sus versiones:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/boom": "^10.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "joi": "^17.9.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1"
  }
```

Comment: Pero eso parece es error de quien envia los datos... y código de eso no has puesto en la pregunta.

Comment: @Pipe gracias por contestar, actualize la pregunta y agrege todo los archivos en el proyecto espero sea de utilidad

Comment: Pase el proyecto a otra computadora y ahi si funciona, no se cual pueda ser el error pero eso soluciono el problema, formateare la computadora

Comment: Formatie mi computadora y eso no soluciono el problema, ni idea de cual pueda ser el problema que por lo visto tiene mi computadora